# Unexpected code printed instead of executed

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to have a field that the user can input YouTube embed code. In the post loop I have this code:

```
            $embed_code = get_field( 'video_embed_code' );

            if ( $embed_code ) {

                echo do_shortcode( '[row]<div class="video-embed-code">' . $embed_code . '</div>[/row]' ); 

            } else
```

(the else statement gets an image and it is working properly no errors) The output is unexpectedly doing this in the browser though:

[image]

Why is it printing that iframe code not executing it?

Comment: you should select HTML instead of none on the settings in the admin..

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the answer. I didn't realize that was an option!

Comment: no problem.. glad you sorted it out now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer as @reikyoushin mentioned above is to change the "Format" settings to "Convert HTML into tags". I didn't realize that was a setting... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You should accept this as an answer to your question, so it doesn't show up as unanswered :)